# Story Identification: cyborg, starship, self-destruction

Tags: story-identification, tv, spaceship, cyborg

I am looking for a TV show / movie that aired in 90's, but the show itself could be older. Here's what I remember, but I might have got it a bit mixed up:

People on a starship found an ancient earth radio station signal and then they picked up an unknown cyborg. The cyborg does not have knowledge as to why is he there, but they found that the cyborg have a bomb inside his body. It ends up with the cyborg not wanting to destroy the starship with the bomb, so he used his human hand to tear the cybernetics on his face to end himself.

It was from my childhood memory and I just got curious about it. Thanks for any help in advance and sorry if I mixed some of details up.

Answer (score -1):

In Star Trek- the new generation, there was an episode where a Borg was found and brought to Enterprise. Initially, because the borg began to have self consciousness, the Enterprise crew fought of using it like some sort of ,,bomb'' , to infect the cyborgs with singularity. Here ius the link to the episode on Wikipedia http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/I,_Borg

I don't remember an episode where a Borg commited suicide to save the human crew.